# Quotient Ring of $F_2$ Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F_2$ be the field of two elements.

I have two questions:

1) Is it true that $F_2[X]/(X^2)\cong F_2\oplus F_2$?

I got the above result by considering $\phi:F_2[X]\to span\{1, X\}\cong F_2\oplus F_2$, via $\phi(\sum a_iX^i)=a_0+a_1X$. The kernel is then $(X^2)$.

2) Is $F_2[X]/(1+X)\cong F_2$?

Quotient out $(1+X)$ is like setting $1+X=0$, i.e. $X=-1=1\pmod 2$ (is this even valid?) so $F_2[X]/(1+X)$ behaves like the constants $F_2$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: (1)-(2)  As rings, as groups, as algebras , as...?

Comment: As rings, I suppose

Comment: Nice. But then you *must* prove your $\;\phi\;$ is a homomorphism of rings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1) $F_2\times F_2$ does not have any nilpotent elements.

2) Yes if you believe that the map that evaluates polynomials at a fixed element of $F$ is a homomorphism, then you can define a map from $F[x]\to F$ that evaluates at $-1$ and and argue its kernel is $(X+1)$. You can just use the factor theorem.

Comment: Thanks. So 1) is false since $X+(X^2)$ is a nilpotent element.

Comment: @ yoyostein exactly, yes